# does daemonset need RBAC in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

When I deploy a deamonset in kubernetes(1.7+), i.e, nginx ingress as daemonset, do I need to set some rbac rule ??? I know I need to set some rbac rule if I use deployment.

Comment: Do you see an error or something doesn't work?

Comment: 7 launch.go:130] ✖ It seems the cluster it is running with Authorization enabled (like RBAC) and there is no permissions for the ingress controller. Please check the configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy ingress, you need to enable some RBAC rules. In the nginx controller repository you can find the RBAC rules: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/examples/rbac/nginx/nginx-ingress-controller-rbac.yml

Answer (score 1):

To create daemonset you don't need to create RBAC rules for it. You might need RBAC for what is running in your Pod, be it via Deployment, Daemonset or whatever. It is the software you're running inside that might want to interact with kubernetes API, like it is in case of Ingress Controller. So, it is in fact irrelevant how you make the Pod happen, the RBAC (Cluster)Role, bindings etc. It is what soft you deploy, that defines what access rules it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable RBAC using helm (`--set rbac.create=true`) and this error is not seen anymore, and the nginx ingress controller is working as expected!

```
helm install --name my-release stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
```